# R Viz for comparing multiple paired values

Tags: r

I have and excel with data for 2 DBs and multiple Measures (Msr) for each. There is  classic ratio data  `Num/Denom=Ratio` for each. Can anybody suggest what visualization I can use in R to graphically find big differences (let say 10%+) for each of measure between Test and X1 databases and then for each Measure.

So we compare  Denom, Num, Rate between line 1 and 2.
    ..and then 3,4
    ..and then 5,6 etc

Tried to do in Excel but read that R could be much better for this purposes. But for now I can see most paired viz works for scattered display. I need something more traditional e.g. in my sample we can mark `X1.SRB.Rare` as low
In my example I have 3 measures, in reality could be 30.  Thanks much for info.
M

```
db  <- c('test','x1','test','x1','test','x1')
msr <- c('BCS','BCS','CCS','CCS','SRB','SRB')
denom <- c(11848,11049,35836,38458,54160,56387)
num <- c(5255,6376,16908,18124,26253,15000)
rate <- c(44.35,57.71,47.18,47.13,48.47,26.6)


df <- data.frame(db,msr,denom,num,rate)
df
    db msr denom   num  rate
1 test BCS 11848  5255 44.35
2   x1 BCS 11049  6376 57.71
3 test CCS 35836 16908 47.18
4   x1 CCS 38458 18124 47.13
5 test SRB 54160 26253 48.47
6   x1 SRB 56387 15000 26.60
```

Comment: Too many buzz words, eg "viz",  and lack of precision in the request, eg "Paired viz",  for a specific answer. Voting to close as too broad. Read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this should do what you want. I reshaped the data so you have one row per msr with separate columns for each db. I used `data.table` for it's performance.

```r
library(data.table)
db  <- c('test','x1','test','x1','test','x1')
msr <- c('BCS','BCS','CCS','CCS','SRB','SRB')
denom <- c(11848,11049,35836,38458,54160,56387)
num <- c(5255,6376,16908,18124,26253,15000)
rate <- c(44.35,57.71,47.18,47.13,48.47,26.6)

df <- data.frame(db,msr,denom,num,rate)
#set as a data.table
setDT(df)
#cast into one row per MSR - fill in with the "rate" variable
out <- dcast(msr ~ db, data = df, value.var = "rate")
#Compute difference
out[, test_x1_diff := test - x1]
#filter out diff >= 10
out[abs(test_x1_diff) >= 10]
#>    msr  test    x1 test_x1_diff
#> 1: BCS 44.35 57.71       -13.36
#> 2: SRB 48.47 26.60        21.87
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Tx Chase, Cubs go!